# Swift 3 Core Data "Entity" error: `Use of undeclared type`

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift3, xcode8

`Use of undeclared type 'Transcription'`

I'm following this simple tutorial of Core Data in Swift 3 (https://learnappdevelopment.com/uncategorized/how-to-use-core-data-in-ios-10-swift-3/)

and I get the above error on the line: `let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Transcription> = Transcription.fetchRequest()`

I double checked and the Entity "Transcription" is spelled correctly in my .xcdatamodeld file

The tutorial was designed for Swift 3, but there was another change since it was released that I fixed, so I'm guessing some other change to Swift in the past 2 months has caused this error.

I'm brand new to Core Data, so I don't know how to debug this.  I'd be very grateful for a solution!

Comment: import CoreData to your class

Answer (score 15):

Dont forget `import CoreData` to your subclass

Answer (score 12):

This happened possibly as Xcode is **unable to determine the path** of the `.xcdatamodel`, a related error can be seen when cleaning the the project. This error happen to one of my project when **changing the name** of the `.xcdatamodel`.

Resolution involves the following:

- go to **Product -> Clean (Shift-Cmd-K)**
- if the error persists

  - **Ctrl-click (right-click)** the problematic `.xcdatamodel` -> **Show in Finder**
  - **Drag** the `.xcdatamodel` to import to the project, a new entry should be created
  - **Remove** the previous `.xcdatamodel` entry.
- **Build (Cmd-B)** to confirm the fix

Comment: If you have the described error in Xcode try to build the project. If the build is successful do the way above and the error in Xcode will be removed!

Comment: This solved the problem for me, thank you! Do you know what can cause this situation in the first place?

Answer (score 8):

I was troubled the same error,I used to Xcode 8.2.1 . I cleaned the project ,closed the Xcode and reopen it ,the error was eliminated after building.

Answer (score 5):

Highlight the Data Model, go to Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass...

This solved the error

Comment: Great PlateReverb,

Comment: I tried that for my entity Quote, then I started getting "Invalid redeclaration of  'Quote'. I'm using Xcode 8.3

Answer (score 5):

In my case, `Xcode` wasn't finding the automatically generated class, which is something like that:

```swift
//
//  Teste+CoreDataClass.swift
//  
//
//  Created by Laura Corssac on 2/2/20.
//
//  This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.
//

import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Teste)
public class Teste: NSManagedObject { }
```

After quitting `Xcode` and reopening it, my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

Using Xcode Version 8.2 beta (8C30a), when I add or modify the entity, I get the same error.  In the data model inspector, change the Codegen option back to Manual/None, as if I was going to generate the dynamic classes myself.  Save, then change back to Category/Extension, and it seemed to work.  (I also had tried cleaning the project with Option-Clean, restarting XCode, but was able to reproduce it easily.)  Hope the upgrade 8.3 beta fixes this bug.

Comment: Thank you. Your post got me over the finish line. Here's an post I found that explains the various settings. https://useyourloaf.com/blog/core-data-code-generation/

Answer (score 0):

No. 
1) We create subclass, go to Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass...
Then replace subclass files to the folder to the same project:

[image: Creating NSManagedObject]

2) then delete files in derivedData - in Xcode -> Preferences:

[image: Deleting derivedData]

3) and then delete reference to old files of NSManagedObject Subclass, because they create automatically system:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to delete my entity that was giving me the error, in your case 'Transcription', from my .xcdatamodeld file and then re-add it again by hand.